# Definir MIME-type de um arquivo no Android

Tags: android, mime-type

Estou precisando descobrir dinamicamente qual o MIME-type de um arquivo. Inicialmente, preciso apenas identificar vídeos, mas pretendo usar isso para identificar páginas HTML, fotos, PDF etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Informações extraídas e mineradas a partir [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31691791/4438007) no SO internacional

Se você não tiver acesso direto ao arquivo (como, por exemplo, estar disponível via FTP ou via HTTP), você pode tentar resgatar o MIME-type pela extensão do arquivo. A classe `android.webkit.MimeTypeMap` tem exatamente o que se precisa para isso. Veja o método [`getMimeTypeFromExtension`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html#getMimeTypeFromExtension(java.lang.String)).

```
 public String getMimeType(Uri uri) {
    String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString());
    return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension.toLowerCase());
}
```

Caso esteja com acesso local, pode-se tentar também usar o [`ContentResolver.getType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getType(android.net.Uri)).

```
public String getMimeType(Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    return cr.getType(uri);
}
```

Na documentação do `getType` não há menção de como ele faz a descoberta. Talvez seja pela extensão, talvez pelos [números mágicos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files) do arquivo, o que é uma detecção muito mais confiável do que pela simples extensão.

Como descobrir se o acesso é direto? Bem, podemos ver em qual *scheme* o conteúdo se encontra. Se for [`SCHEME_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#SCHEME_CONTENT), [`SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE) ou [`SCHEME_FILE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#SCHEME_FILE), então é seguro considerar como local:

```
public boolean contentSchemeLocal(Uri uri) {
    String scheme = uri.getScheme();

    return scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE) ||
        scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE) ||
        scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT);
}

public String getMimeType(Uri uri) {
    if (contentSchemaLocal(uri)) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        return cr.getType(uri);
    } else {
        String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString());
        return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```