# Verificar é imagem Curl

Tags: php, libcurl

Existe alguma maneira através  do pedido Curl de saber se é uma imagem ou não?

```
$ch = curl_init($image_url);
$name = generateRandomString();
$fp = fopen($caminho.'/'.$name.'.png', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Sei qual é o url mas o meu problema são aquelas que não termina em png,jpg...

Comment: Por exemplo isto é uma imagem e  o url nao tem nada que indique isso http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pMWnZMwH1c6exwP71cqLZ0BYtMSUwIaS-7wwEg9SYLvtRj5PFUlYhXtUvT7goUqeo2UBI29XeU-fFddJmcB1DNe1=s240

Comment: É verdade sim, tens razão

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma é usando o `finfo_buffer`, por exemplo:

```
if(finfo_buffer(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $conteudo) === 'image/jpeg'){
    // O $conteudo é um 'image/jpeg'
}
```

Não sei quão seguro isto é. No entanto o uso dessa biblioteca está recomendado na  própria documentação do PHP, [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

> Do not use `getimagesize()` to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the [Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) extension instead.

---

Em testes, isto funciona da seguinte forma:

```
$ch = curl_init($image_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
$conteudo = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(finfo_buffer(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $conteudo) === 'image/jpeg'){
    file_put_contents(
        unpack('H*', random_bytes(32))[1].'.jpg',
        $conteudo
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a função [`curl_getinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) que retornará o `contentType`, a partir daí você pode utilizar uma validação para os tipos de imagem que necessita:

```
 $contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
 if($contentType == 'image/png') {
     echo 'Formato válido';
 }
```

Comment: Lembrando que isso pode ser falsificado pelo "cliente" (pelo alvo do curl), é possível ter um corpo com um conteúdo qualquer, que não é imagem, e com o cabeçalho de `Content-Type: image/png`.

Comment: Sim, ainda há essa possibilidade. Mas se não for uma fonte confiável, ele terá de efetuar outros tratamentos.

Comment: Eu precisei detectar o tipo de um MIME-type em Android (solução para essa questão no Android [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216529/64969)). Lá ele tem um tal de `ContentResolver.getType`, que talvez descubra o MIME-type pela leitura dos números mágicos, o que tornaria seguro contra essa falsificação. Não tem nada que faça isso no PHP não?

Comment: Tem sim, @JeffersonQuesado. Possivelmente esse método trabalha parecido com o [`exif_imagetype`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php). Até mencionei essa função na resposta para a pergunta [Qual é a forma mais segura para se identificar que o arquivo de upload é uma imagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178737/qual-%C3%A9-a-forma-mais-segura-para-se-identificar-que-o-arquivo-de-upload-%C3%A9-uma-ima/178749#178749)

Comment: `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);` não verifica o conteudo, verifica apenas o header content-type.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o [`Content-type`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) é feito justamente pra isso: descrever o tipo do conteúdo. Há possibilidade de ser adulterada? Sim. Mas se a fonte de onde ele está fazendo a requisição não é confiável, então necessitará de uma série de tratamentos de segurança para a aplicação dele.

Comment: O Content-Type pode ser facilmente manipulado, não por maldade, mas por algum erro, por exemplo a imagem é gerada dinamicamente, mas o script falhou e ainda sim foi enviado o mime-type de imagem.